# Qt QSpinBox accelerated step size

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QSpinBox` in Qt. The widget comes with one increaseValue and one decreaseValue arrow. Clicking the arrow increases the value as determined by `singleStep`, while pressing and holding the arrow increases the value by `singleStep` every X milliseconds (depending on system settings).

What is the best way to implement an experience where pressing and holding will increase / decrease the value faster as times goes on. I am thinking of either

- Start with `singleStep` increments for the first 2 seconds, then increment by `2 * singleStep`, then `4 * singleStep`, until released
- Increment by `singleStep` every X milliseconds, then after the first 2 seconds of holding the arrow pressed, increment by `singleStep` every X / 2 milliseconds, etc

Whichever is easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first suggestion you should try the built-in functionality of the `QSpinBox`.

```
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto w=new QSpinBox;
    w->setAccelerated(true);
    w->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!